# How to achieve the below two requirements through shell script commands?

Tags: shell, unix

Please help acheving the below two requirements through a unix shell script commands.

Requirement 1:  If there are "N" columns in a flat file; In the 5th column of the flat file , 
                blind update with "def" should be done ,irrespective of the value present 
                there(value can be anything ex: abc,xyx,foo,den etc ).remaining other column values data should remain unchanged

Requirement 2:  If there are "N" columns in a flat file; In the 5th column of the flat file,if the value is present as "abc" 
                it should be replaced with "def",remaining 
                other column values data should remain unchanged.

Regards,
Srihari

Comment: and I assume you tried something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk`: Set your delimiter in the `BEGIN` statement. If delimiter is space then remove `BEGIN` statement.

**Requirement 1:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i==5){$i="def"}}1' your_file
```

**Requirement 2:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i==5 && $i=="abc"){$i="def"}}1' your_file
```